# How to add js library in Angular CLI 6 Project?

Tags: javascript, angular, leaflet, angular-cli

I have been unable to include any of the libraries below in my project:

https://github.com/w8r/leaflet-area-select

https://github.com/heyman/leaflet-areaselect

Any direction/help would be appreciated!

Comment: did you add the js into the angular.json ?

Answer (score 1):

```
    Step - 1
    npm install --save leaflet leaflet-area-select

    Step - 2
    Add in angular.json under Scripts section

     "scripts": [
                  "node_modules/leaflet/dist/leaflet.js",
                  "node_modules/leaflet-area-select/dist/Map.SelectArea.min.js"
                ]


    Step - 3
Declare a variable with name L (Because L refers to Leaflet as $ refers to jQuery) in the component where you want to use SelectArea
i.e.
Declare var L: any;

Step - 4
Use variable L to get instance of SelectArea
i.e.
Console.log(L.Map.SelectArea)
```

Comment: thank you a lot ! the best clear steps that I ever see bro :) you saved my life.